# Get File Attributes for system folders on Windows 8

Tags: java, file, windows-8.1

How can I get the attributes for system folders such as `Libraries, Network` etc using `Java 8` on `Windows 8.1 x64` OS?

I've tried the common way:

```
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
```

And it causes an exception like `"No such directory"`

After debug, I have found out that:

1. If file is a `ShellFolder` instance, its absolute path looks like `"C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\TestProject\::{folder uuid}"` and `Paths.get()` throws an exception `Illegal char ':'`
2. If create the file from String `"Desktop\Libraries"`, the `Paths.get()` would work OK, but `file.exists() == false` and `Files.getFileAttributeView()` would throw an exception `No such directory`

So how can get the attributes for Windows System Folders and is it possible at all?

**UPD:**

1. [ShellFolder description](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/shell/ShellFolder.java)
2. `System Folder` is an integral part of Windows File System Core

Comment: Why do you `Paths.get()` the result of a `File`'s `.getAbsolutePath()` object??

Comment: Because full file path is necessary parameter for `Paths.get()`, isn't it?

Comment: Of course not! By default paths will be computed from the JVM's working directory. Just pass a String argument...

Comment: It works for all other files, does not work only for system folders... Ok, what String should I pass there?

Comment: OK, first of all, what do you call a "shell folder" anyway? Also, what do you call "system folders"? I'm afraid I do Unix only, so I fail to understand those.

Comment: OK, that does not explain anything to me. First of all, it appears that a `ShellFolder` is nothing like a real, live file on disk; so it is not surprising that java.nio.file yells at it (and yes, a path component in Windows cannot have a colon in it); as to system folders, they have to be located somewhere on disk as well

Comment: The Libraries aren't file system objects and cannot be properly represented by paths or file API. The GUID notation mentioned is a junction which explains how the shell should find the appropriate COM object to display in that location. It looks like the ShellFolder object is designed for what you want and the ShellFolderManager will allow you to get a ShellFolder object for known locations such as Desktop, Documents, etc.